# Convert values from map into set

Tags: java, collections, hashset

I have a map of string to list of string `Map<String, List<String>>`
Is this the most efficient way to create a Set from the values in the map

```
for (List<String> localList : map.values()) {
    set.addAll(localList);
}
```

Comment: Use a profiler to measure bottle necks in your code. This is much more accurate than asking on SO or guessing about efficiencies yourself.

Comment: You could probably write a one liner using a stream, but I don't see any way around iterating your collection of lists, and adding each one to the total set.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen maybe this? `Set<String> set = map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());` Although might be hard to quantify the improvement in efficiency without looking deep into the source I suspect.

Comment: @Mena You rock, bro, and I'll bet that might slightly outperform what the OP currently has.

Comment: Why do you need an efficient way ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks :) - not sure I can claim that in terms of performance but it does look fancier to me too :D

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by "most efficient way".

From a performance standpoint, your code is the most efficient.

The code can be simplified using Java 8 Streams, but the performance will degrade a bit, however it's unlikely to be noticeable in the grand scheme of things, so Streams is likely "more efficient".

It is however mostly a matter of opinion which is better.

For comparison, your code:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
for (List<String> localList : map.values()) {
    set.addAll(localList);
}
```

Compared to Stream version:

```
Set<String> set = map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Which for readability can be written as:

```
Set<String> set = map.values()
                     .stream()
                     .flatMap(List::stream)
                     .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

If you want to control the type of `Set`, change the last part to:

```
                     .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Comment: for the streaming version may be it will work faster if you add .parallel() after .stream()

Comment: @xyz Unlikely. If the `Set` is not concurrent, all values will eventually have to be added to a single `Set` anyway, so multi-threading is a waste. If the `Set` is concurrent, all values can technically be added to the final `Set` in multiple threads, but the overhead of even using multiple threads, and the degradation of collisions when inserting, will outweigh the gain in performance, unless you have to process a *huge* amount of values.

Answer (score 1):

At the `Set` interface, it will be the same for any surrounding code

```
... other code ...
mySet.add(item);
... other code ...
```

The performance implications come from the kinds of loops you put around the call to add the item to the set. (Ok, the kind of `Set` matters too, but that's the easiest thing to change).

Generally, `Iterators` are a bit slower, and indexes are a bit faster; but that's a generalization.  The "foreach" loop tends to favor an autogenerated iterator approach, at lest up to Java8.  I haven't investigated versions past that.  For specific details, one needs to benchmark.

Generally, the additional overhead of the hidden objects used in a stream (Collectors, Producers, etc) also lead to a higher number of objects being processed, where some of those objects were the plumbing framework of the processing environment pushing items through the stream.  Again, in my benchmarking (up to Java8) this had a significant impact, one which was mostly avoided by direct indexing using a traditional C style `for` loop approach.

*Now the caveats*

I was using `ArrayLists` exclusively, so it makes perfect sense that my performance would be faster in pulling items out by their indexes.  I have no idea what the concrete class is of your lists.

Also, I didn't have my lists stored in a `Map`, so again, it will depend to some degree what you are using for your map.

*Advice*

There are too many choices to make, each choice working better in one or another situation, to really know this kind of information beforehand.  I would highly suggest taking a baseline set of measurements for typical (yet different) Maps of Lists of this kind, and then trying out small alterations rerunning your benchmarks.  This is the only way to really understand performance impacts in an optimizing environment.  Everything else is just guesswork.

Comment: And I am going to ignore the people who think "most efficient" is least number of characters typed into a source code file.  That kind of code golf in production can sometimes lead to very poor efficiency, and is valuing one's personal time while ignoring the run time characteristics of their product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've meant performance as a key for *most efficient way*. In this case simple benchmark can provide the best answer. Here's a simple JMH benchmark for you:

```
package test;

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ListOfStringsToSetBenchmark {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        org.openjdk.jmh.Main.main(args);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(value = 1, warmups = 1)
    @Measurement(iterations = 5)
    @Warmup(iterations = 3)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void streams() {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("test", Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
        map.put("test2", Arrays.asList("4", "5", "6"));
        map.put("test3", Arrays.asList("7", "8", "9"));

        Set<String> collect = map.values().stream().flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(value = 1, warmups = 1)
    @Measurement(iterations = 5)
    @Warmup(iterations = 3)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void parallelStreams() {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("test", Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
        map.put("test2", Arrays.asList("4", "5", "6"));
        map.put("test3", Arrays.asList("7", "8", "9"));

        Set<String> collect = map.values().parallelStream().flatMap(Collection::parallelStream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(value = 1, warmups = 1)
    @Measurement(iterations = 5)
    @Warmup(iterations = 3)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
    public void forEach() {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("test", Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"));
        map.put("test2", Arrays.asList("4", "5", "6"));
        map.put("test3", Arrays.asList("7", "8", "9"));

        Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();

        for (List<String> localList : map.values()) {
            set.addAll(localList);
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
Benchmark                              Mode  Cnt        Score        Error  Units
ListOfStringsToSetBenchmark.forEach          thrpt    5  5290023,805 ±  89846,320  ops/s
ListOfStringsToSetBenchmark.parallelStreams  thrpt    5   588714,960 ±   6289,819  ops/s
ListOfStringsToSetBenchmark.streams          thrpt    5  2940686,522 ± 359335,288  ops/s
```

*NOTE:* For precise results you need to increment iteration values.

Comment: You might also try a parallel version using a `ConcurrentSkipListSet` collector with the `CONCURRENT` characteristic.